# How to check if a woocommerce product has any category assigned to it?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a custom plugin where related products are fetched as per the tags assigned to a product. I am facing an issue. When i run a loop it gives me a warning message. What i want to check is that if the particular product has any category assigned to it. How can i check if any category has been assigned to a woocommerce product. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**my custom code**

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product;
    global $post;

    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->post->ID) );
    $terms200 = get_the_terms( $loop->post->ID, 'product_cat' );


        // if(!empty($terms200) || $terms200!='' || $terms200!=null){   
    if (get_category($loop->post->ID)->category_count != 0){        
        $content.='<li class="product-small  grid1 grid-normal">';
            $content.='<div class="inner-wrap">';
                $content.='<a href="'.get_the_permalink($loop->post->ID).'">';
                    $content.='<div class="product-image hover_fade_in_back">';
                        $content.='<div class="front-image">';
                            $content.='<img src="'.$feat_image.'" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" style="width:247px !important;height:300px !important;" />';
                        $content.='</div>';
                    $content.='</div>';
                $content.='</a>';
                $content .='<div class="info style-grid1">';
                    $content .='<div class="text-center">';
                        $count=1;
                        foreach ( @$terms200 as $term ) {
                                if($count==1){
                                    $content.='<h5 class="category"><a href="'.get_site_url().'/?product_cat='.$term->slug.'" rel="tag">'.$term->name.'</a></h5>';  
                                    $content.='<div class="tx-div small"></div>';   
                                }
                            $count++;
                        }
                        $content .='<a href="'.get_the_permalink($loop->post->ID).'"><p class="name">'.$loop->post->post_title.'</p></a>';
                        if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) :
                        $content .='<span class="price"><span class="amount">'.$price_html.'</span></span>';
                        endif;
                        $content.='<div class="mycustomcartbuttonbox">[add_to_cart id="'.$loop->post->ID.'"]</div>';                                
                    $content .='</div>';
                $content .='</div>';
            $content.='</div>';
        $content.='</li>';
        echo do_shortcode($content);

    }   

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually really simple to do that.

Just type inside of your loop:

```
if(!has_category("uncategorized")){
 //do stuff
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could try:

```
if(!has_term( 'uncategorized', 'product_cat' )){
  //do stuff
}
```

You can learn more about it at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category

Comment: @NitinJohnson Im confident it will, i've edited my post to an alternative if it doesn't work.

Comment: @NitinJohnson - you need to use has_term for WooCommerce.

Comment: has_term( 'category_name', 'product_cat', $product->post ) do the trick