# How can I set tab (only) if the product is in a certain category WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have a tab set to add a tab which contains specifications in WooCommerce. I'd like to wrap it into an if statement to only set the tab if the product is part of a certain category.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );

function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    global $post;

    if ($product->is_category("Mobile Phones")) { 
        $tabs['custom_specification'] = array( 'title' => __( 'Specification', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 50, 'callback' => 'woo_custom_specification_content' );
    }
}
```

What is the right code to check the category for WooCommerce in the if statements brackets?

Comment: I didn't forget I just didn't add it to save space I solved this problem about ten minutes after I posted the question will upload answer

Comment: Yes your's is kind of the same as my conclusion except I used ```if ($product->is_type( 'grouped' )  && has_term( 'SIM Cards', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'SIM Cards', 'product_cat' ) )```

Comment: obviously after declaring ```$product = get_product( $post->ID );```

Comment: I have the same sorta code for mobile phones my question was how to check product category the above is just an example of the same thing I did with SIM cards

Comment: ```has_term``` was what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional `is_category()` will return true if you are on a category archive page.

As you need a conditional for single product pages, you will target single product pages with **`is_product()`** conditional combined this way:

```
if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Mobile Phones', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    $tabs['custom_specification'] = array( 'title' => __( 'Specification', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 50, 'callback' => 'woo_custom_specification_content' );
}
```

Or you could try also, in case, this one too:

```
if( is_product() && has_category( 'Mobile Phones' ) ) {
    $tabs['custom_specification'] = array( 'title' => __( 'Specification', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 50, 'callback' => 'woo_custom_specification_content' );
}
```

---

**@edit:** You've missed `return $tabs;` at the end of your function before last closing bracket **`}`**.

---

References:

- [Remove product content based on category](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/remov-product-content-based-on-category/)
- [How to check if a woocommerce product has any category assigned to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033273/how-to-check-if-a-woocommerce-product-has-any-category-assigned-to-it)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code. This code add woocommerce tab only when product has  **Mobile Phones** category.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );

    function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

      global $post;
     if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Mobile Phones', 'product_cat' )) 
     { 
      $tabs['custom_specification'] = array( 'title' => __( 'Specification', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 50, 'callback' => 'woo_custom_specification_content' );
      }
      return $tabs;
    }
```

Comment: Kindly, but you are just copying my answer!

Comment: I correct the question code and add solution of issue .  return $tabs; row is missing in question code.

Comment: Yes but you are just copying my conditionals… so avoid this… thanks. The Op question is relative to conditionals. The `return $tabs;` is just an an oversight from the OP. You can add a comment in OP question for that…