# WooCommerce Checkout url hook - Change condition based on product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, categories

Wondering if anyone could help me to customize this code. I would like to change the applied condition in this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'change_checkout_url', 30 );
function change_checkout_url( $url ) {
    $allowed_countries = array('NO');
    $customer_country = WC()->customer->get_default_country();
    if( !in_array( $customer_country , $allowed_countries ) ) {
        $url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' );
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Is it possible instead, for products that belongs to some category in WooCommerce, to have a custom checkout url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2020 Update: Only for WooCommerce 3+

Yes it's possible, making some changes:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'custom_checkout_url', 30 );
function custom_checkout_url( $checkout_url ) {

    // Define your product categories (term Id, slug or name)
    $categories = array('Cat name1', 'Cat name2'); 
    $custom_url = 'http://my_custom_url.com/checkout/'; // <= custom URL

    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    if ( sizeof($cart_items) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item ) {
            if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
                 return $custom_url;
            }
        }
    }
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

*This code goes in your plugin file or on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

References:

- [Display WooCommerce checkout link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/display-a-checkout-link-in-a-template-file/)
- [Using has_term( $category, 'product_cat') for WC products category condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613769/how-can-i-set-tab-only-if-the-product-is-in-a-certain-category-woocommerce/38623854#38623854)
- [Get Cart products id on checkout WooCommerce page, to display product images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798888/get-cart-products-id-on-checkout-woocommerce-page-to-display-product-images/38804401#38804401)

Comment: Great! Exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately it's not working as some of the code is deprecated or removed. I tried to update but I'm still not getting it to work. [Change Checkout Url in WooCommerce depneding on cart-content (product category)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465027/change-checkout-url-in-woocommerce-depending-on-cart-content-product-category)

Comment: Works well. Thank you